# Could not find the level of last node of the graph

Tags: c++, graph

I want to print the level of each node. I could print the level of every node but the last node. Please help me to debug the code to find out why my code is not printing the level of the last node.
For the below sample input/output it **printed level of node 10** is **0**
The actual level of node 10 is 4.

**Graphical representation of the sample input graph is given below**
[image]

**input**

```
10 14  
1 2  
1 4  
1 3  
2 6  
4 7 
3 7  
3 8  
6 10  
7 9  
8 5  
8 7  
9 10  
5 10
```

**My output**

```
Level of 1 is :0  
Level of 2 is :1  
Level of 3 is :1  
Level of 4 is :1  
Level of 5 is :3  
Level of 6 is :2  
Level of 7 is :2  
Level of 8 is :2  
Level of 9 is :3  
Level of 10 is :0
```

**code**

```
int main() {
    int N, E;
    scanf("%d%d", & N, & E);
    int level[N];
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        level[i] = -1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= E; i++) {
        int x, y;
        scanf("%d%d", & x, & y);
        edges[x].push_back(y);
    }
    int source = 1;
    level[source] = 0;
    for (int i = source; i <= N; i++) {
        int l = edges[i].size();

        printf("Node %d is connected to: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            printf("%d ", edges[i][j]);
            if (level[edges[i][j]] == -1) {
                level[edges[i][j]] = level[i] + 1;
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int size = sizeof(level) / sizeof(int);
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        printf("Level of %d is :%d\n", i, level[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*I do not understand what I am missing here.*

Comment: Please share your code here, not in pastebin

Comment: Care to format your question nicely? It is really hard to read and understand. Thanks for the update~

Comment: "Node 3 is connected to: 7 8" but actually Node 3 is also connected to Node 1. I am thinking that you are only checking for connection to lower and same level nodes but not higher level ones. Hence why your code prints that Node 10 is not connected to anything. It is really hard to see on pastebin. Can you please share your code here instead? @Sudipto

Comment: I tried to format my post and share my code here but couldn't.I didn't able to format code snipets.This is my first post and I am sorry

Comment: You can just paste your code in the post and use `CTRL+K` to format it into a code block @Sudipto

Comment: Reduce your problem to a minimal but complete example, and post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your time Tacocat.Could you please Modify my code and Share here.

Comment: I assumed It as a directed graph @Tacocat

Comment: @Sudipto, there are a lot of errors in your code. Fixing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 100000

vector<int> edges[MAX];
vector<int> vis[MAX];

int main() {

    int numNodes, numEdges; // number of edges

    // reading number of nodes
    printf("Please input number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &numNodes);
    // reading number of edges
    printf("Please input number of edges: ");
    scanf("%d", &numEdges);
    int level[numNodes];

    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        level[i] = -1;
    }

    // reading edges
    printf("Please input the %d edges in the form of \"NODE1 NODE2\":\n", numEdges);
    for (int i = 0; i < numEdges; i++) {
        int x, y;
        scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
        edges[x-1].push_back(y);
        edges[y-1].push_back(x);
        printf("\nEdge #%d stored! Please input %d more edge(s).\n", i+1, 13-i-1);
    }

    level[0] = 0;

    // printing edges for all nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        int l = edges[i].size();

        printf("Node %d is connected to: ", i+1);

        if (l == 0) {
            printf("nothing!\n", i+1);
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", edges[i][j]);

        // update nodes' levels
        /* if the adjacent node's level is lower than the current node's level and the adjacent node node is the larger node,
        OR if the adjacent node's level is -1 (means it had not been updated yet),
        then the adjacent node's level should be changed to the current node's level + 1.
        This is possible because it implicitly appears that higher numbered nodes are given higher levels,
        e.g. when 1 is connected by an edge to 2, it is assumed that 2 is at level 1 and 2 is at level 0,
        rather than the other way around.*/
        if (((level[edges[i][j]-1] < level[i]) && (edges[i][j] > i+1)) || (level[edges[i][j]-1] == -1)) {
            level[edges[i][j]-1] = level[i] + 1;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // printing level of all nodes
    for(int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        printf("Level of node %d is: %d\n", i+1, level[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Some changes I have made:

1. Refactored the code to include better indentations, variable names and slight commentation.
2. Fixed the indexes used for the various loops. Your code would have asked scanned for 13 edges when you input that there were to be 14.
3. Made it bidirectional storage of edges so as to print all adjacent edges for each node.
4. Fixed the update process of the nodes' level.
5. Removed unnecessary variables.
6. Added additional console messages.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution But your code prints same as mine but you assumed the graph is un directed that is edges are bidirectional.Thats ok but How Level of 10 be 0. It should be 4.I edited the post and added an image also please see.Thanks

Comment: You question was unclear. I thought your question was regarding the missing print for the line `Node 10 is connected to:`.

Comment: Btw, your code may print the same, as you put it, but you were taking in the wrong value for the number of edges. If you were to count the number of edges you input, it is clearly only 13, not 14.

Comment: I apologize for unclear ques.Can you please help me to print the level of 10 for above output

Comment: Hey would you please explain why this condition (level[edges[i][j]-1] == -1) does not work for last node.And what this condition actually checks (level[edges[i][j]-1] < level[i]) && (edges[i][j] > i+1))

Comment: I have added my explanation to the code itself as a comment. Please ignore my earlier commented explanation as it was poorly written. Thanks! @Sudipto